# Spring boot : best release of angular to start with

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm newbie to spring boot and angular and I want to know which is the best version of angular (2,4,5 or 6) to use as a front end framework when we use spring boot as back end.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, this question is primarily opinion based, and as such it's difficult to give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the latest version of anything.

So angular 6 + spring boot latest version would be the best choice.

If you are planning to use combination of angular and Spring boot then have a look at [Jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) as this community is very active on github and all related forums and developing very rich and best practices code.